# Default Form inheritance from other Classes

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I´m having some trouble with my C# Windows Forms application:
In the Default "Form1" class, which is automatically created by Visual Studio, i have a few UI elements like events for Buttons-Press, TextBoxes, etc.
I want to seperate the UI elements as much as possible from the actual Logic. My plan was to put all methods, that interact with the "Backend" into a seperate class and call them from the Forms1 class (e.g. with via a Button press), by forms1 inheriting from the new Class.

```
public partial class Form1 : HelpfulMethods
{
    // UI-Elements like Button-Presses, Gridview, etc.
    
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.MehodThatInteractsWiththeBackend()
    }
}
```

```
public class HelpfulMethods
{
    public string MehodThatInteractsWiththeBackend() 
    {
        //This metod will be called from Forms1 and returns something from the "backend"
    }
}
```

However Form1 already inherits from a class called Forms (`public partial class Form1 : Form`), and therefore cant inherit from yet another class.

I´m not sure if my approach even makes sense here.
Is there a Better way to seperate the UI from the Logic? If so, an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You provided only little information, so i can only guess, but I think better way is to use an instance of helpfulmethods inside Form1: `var methods = new HelpfulMethods(); methods.MehodThatInteractsWiththeBackend();`

Comment: You could use the [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) feature or move to design patterns as MVP, MVVM etc.

Comment: You can also make `HelpfulMethods` static, and call its method using `HelpfulMethods.MehodThatInteractsWiththeBackend` while supplying the proper data to that method from within your form.